# Bochner: Lebesgue Obsolete?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Bochner's notion of integral:
$$F\text{ Bochner integrable}:\iff \exists S_n\in\mathcal{S}:\quad \int\|S_m-S_n\|\mathrm{d}\mu\to 0\quad(S_n\to F)$$
This version totally circumvents Lebesgue's notion of integral. But Bochner and Lebesgue agree on complex measurable functions. So the question arises:

Is Lebesgue obsolete? Or are there some important aspects one will miss not introducing it?

Comment: How is Lebesgue obsolete? Which $\int$ do you use on the right hand side of the definition?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: The basic one for simple functions $\int S\mathrm{d}µ:=\sum_k S_kµ(A_k)$ with $S=\sum_k S_k\chi_{A_k}$.

Comment: Your definition of the Bochner integral seems different from [the usual one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral). And $S_n\to F$ in what sense?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: In fact they're equivalent! That is why I mentioned it as a *version*. Besides $S_n\to F$ pointwise.

Comment: Okay … but the Lebesgue integral is also determined by taking limits of the integral of simple functions. The difference seems mainly technical to me. But I would have to study it more carefully to form a stronger opinion.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: Yepp they both go more or less along the same lines so thats why I started thinking why the need for Lebesgue then... Ok, let me know if you wanna know more about it.

Comment: Does the following answer your question? The Lebesgue integral is (almost) a special case of the Bochner integral, where the "target" Banach space is just $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$. **But** this does not cover the case of functions $f:X\to [0,\infty]$, which is sometimes very convenient. Also, the **monotone convergence theorem** can not be formulated for the general Bochner integral (simply because there is no ordering on an arbitrary Banach space), but of course it is valid (suitably formulated) for the Bochner integral, i.e. if $f_n \uparrow f$ and $(\int f_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence, then...

Comment: @PhoemueX: Well, surely every theorem regarding Lebesgue can be formulated into one regarding Bochner as long as one demands finiteness. But honestly, I was never really comfy with numerical functions as those do not really seem to be what one really wants, namely finite integrals, bounded expressions and so on - in the end they seem to be just a fancy way of stating theorems as $sup_n f_n$ always exists. And hand on your heart, did you ever really needed a numerical function that cannot be transformed into one defined to be zero where it was infinite before?

Comment: Numerical functions are very handy for e.g. Fubini's theorem. For example if you want to show that the convolution $f \ast g(x) := \int f(y) g(x-y) dy$ is well-defined a.e. and defines an integrable function, it is nice to be able to consider the **numerical function** $|f|\ast |g|$ and to show that $\int |f|\ast |g| < \infty$. One can of course circumvent this argument somehow, but using numerical functions, it is much easier. As I already said above, if you are only interested in functions with values in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ which are integrable, then Lebesgue is a special case of Bochner.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Ok I agree with you as an intermediate step in proofs they can be **really** convenient - otherwise one would have to bother alot circumventing them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example, suppose that $F : [0,1]\rightarrow X$, where $X$ is a Hilbert space. Suppose that $\|F(t)\|$ is a Lebesgue integrable function. If $(F(t),x)$ is measurable for all $x$, then there is a unique vector--say $\int_{a}^{b}F\,dt$--such that
$$
          \int_{0}^{1}(F(t),x)\,dt = \left(\int_{0}^{1}F\,dt,x\right),\;\;\; x \in X.
$$
This is a very simple integral to define, quite intuitive, powerful, does not require separability, and reduces to the scalar case.

If $X$ is not separable, then I seem to recall that the Bochner integral won't allow you to integrate general such things because $F$ may not be Bochner measurable. But you can definitely see how this might be useful, especially knowing how the integral reduces to scalar cases.

Comment: Ah so your point is that the Lebesgue integral will be useful to integrate those ones that cannot be Bochner integrable due to nonseparable image, is this what you mean? I guess you refer to examples like the $f:[0,1]\to\ell^2([0,1]):t\mapsto\chi_t$. But then the above version could be used to bypass this again as that version allows to generalize to integrate also those ones that cannot be approximated by sequences but nets only.

Comment: Hmm, I see there is another problem: When passing from sequences to nets one has to find a new proof for "well-definedness" as the old one won't work anymore - though it doesn't mean that the integral won't be well-defined anymore...

Comment: @Freeze_S : It is usually trivial to check conditions for integrability of the integral I gave you, but Bochner measurability is not always so easy to establish, especially if you cannot assume a Schauder basis. Properties of the integral I gave you are easier to figure out, too, and this technique works for any reflexive space. Passing to nets is problematic in any measure theory. I think you about have to use Bochner when $X=L^{\infty}$; that case is messy, but what can you do?